# Why does this typeclass only compile with "-XNoMonomorphismRestriction"?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've been getting some strange typeclass errors of the form "No instance for (Test a0) arising from an expression type signature". Here is the simplest version of the offending code I could come up with:

```
class Test a where
  test :: a

foo = test
```

Adding the type doesn't help:

```
foo = test :: Test a => a
```

However, adding an instance of Test does make it compile:

```
instance Test Int where
  test = 0
```

This isn't really acceptable, as I want my instances declared elsewhere.

Finally, passing `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` to ghc(i) also allows it to compile. While this is good enough for now, I don't understand what this extension does, why it is necessary, or what downsides may be lurking.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction

Comment: I found this really helpful: http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/05/towards-understanding-haskells-monomorphism-restriction/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an alternative to disabling the monomorphism restriction for the whole file (which is *fairly* harmless, but can cause some unexpected recalculation of values that are *not* intended to be polymorphic), adding the type *does* help, but you have to do it as a signature at top level:

```
foo :: Test a => a
foo = test
```

If you add it just after `test`, it is considered just an annotation on the subexpression `test`, and does not turn off the monomorphism restriction for `foo` itself.

Comment: Ah ok. I did not realize that those two methods of type declaration were different. This was confusing, as all the resources on monomorphism restriction suggested adding type declarations.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this article](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/05/towards-understanding-haskells-monomorphism-restriction/) I finally understood the monomorphism restriction. The point is that things which look like constants shouldn't be polymorphic, as that might cause them to be evaluated multiple times (at worst resulting in exponential slowdowns).

In my actual case the "constant" was itself a function (via currying). I'm now on the fence; should I resort to `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, or add the type declaration? The latter seems less drastic/intrusive, but on the other hand I just don't like what the MR does to my types.

Comment: Adding type declarations at top level is recommended anyway, as it both documents intent and makes type errors less confusing by not letting type inference cross boundaries between functions.

Comment: The "constant" is varying due to polymorphism, not currying.  And although it's very common to disable the MR, you should add type signatures to top-level declarations anyway.

Comment: @VladFiroiu Yes it's of course handy to remove them to find out what GHCi thinks they should be, but it's considered a good idea to add them again afterward. Also I *highly* recommend the new `-fdefer-type-errors` option which makes it much less annoying to tweak these things when programming.

Comment: I have also heard advice in favor of omitting type declarations. Pros include making functions as general as possible, not having to write out all of the typeclass constraints (annoying if I have lots of helper functions), and making type-level refactoring less burdensome.

Comment: @JohnL Right. The point I was making was that in my case the MR wasn't really saving much computation time, as the cost of computation the function was dominated by the cost of applying it.